# trying to make buttons in Tkinter rewrite a csv file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

Wanting to make buttons that I have place write/add a new column next to the person (I have already made code the identify the person) but I'm trying to allow for the csv file to be rewritten with all the old info, with an additional column of which the user will select out of 3 buttons to choose to make a to fill, this is what I have tried thus far.

```
#opening the csv file
filepath = 'file name'
csvFile = open(filepath)

#reader through the csv file
reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
# turning the csv file into a list. 
Data = list (reader)
list_of_entries = []

list_of_entries.append(Data["Time"])

def TimeBTN15 ():
    Data["Time"] = '15 mins'
    Data["Time"] = newtime

def TimeBTN30 ():
    Data["Time"] = '30 mins'
    Data["Time"] = newtime

def TimeBTN1 ():
    Data["Time"] = '1 Hour'
    Data["Time"] = newtime

TimeLBL = Label(frame3,text="What time would you like to pick up meal:",font=('Arial',18, "bold"),bg = '#F0EAD6')
TimeLBL.place(x= 80, y= 575)

TimenBTN15 = Button(frame, text = '15 mins', font=('Arial',16,),bg = '#F0EAD6',command = TimeBTN15 )
TimenBTN15.place(x= 450, y= 575)

TimenBTN30 = Button(frame, text = '30 min ', font=('Arial',16,),bg = '#F0EAD6',command = TimeBTN30 )
TimenBTN30.place(x= 525, y= 575)

TimenBTN1 = Button(frame, text = ' 1 hour', font=('Arial',16,),bg = '#F0EAD6',command = TimeBTN1 )
TimenBTN1.place(x= 600, y= 575)

csvFile = open('shopoutput.csv', 'w+')

# writting in the headers 
csvFile.write("Name,Food,Drinks,Price,NewTime\n")
    #adding all the new data into the orginal and new data into the shopoutput csv
for data in list_of_entries:
            
        csvFile.write(data['Name'] + ',')
        csvFile.write(data['Food'] + ',')
        csvFile.write(data['Drinks'] + ',')
        csvFile.write(data['Price'] + ',')
        csvFile.write(data['Time'] + '\n')
          
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Do you want the app to write the CSV and exit as soon as they press one of the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help because you didn't give a complete program.  You have a number of issues here.  `Data` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary.  You never copy anything into `list_of_entries`, so that's never going to have your old data.  You can't write anything to the csv file until the user makes some selection -- it has to be in a button response.  Here's an example that seems closer to what you want.

```
#opening the csv file
filepath = 'file name'

with open(filepath) as csvfile:
    csvFile = open(filepath)
    # Read the csv file
    Data = csv.reader(csvFile)

# Add Time to each entry

for row in Data:
    row['Time'] = ''

def writecsv():
    with open('shopoutput.csv', 'w+') as xfile:
        csvFile = csv.DictWriter(xfile, Data[0].keys())
        csvFile.writerows( Data )

def findPerson():
    for row in Data:
        if row['Name'] == targetname:
            return row
    return None

def TimeBTN15 ():
    row = findPerson()
    row["Time"] = '15 mins'
    writecsv()
    sys.exit()

def TimeBTN30 ():
    row = findPerson()
    row["Time"] = '30 mins'
    writecsv()
    sys.exit()

def TimeBTN1 ():
    row = findPerson()
    row["Time"] = '1 Hour'
    writecsv()
    sys.exit()

TimeLBL = Label(frame3,text="What time would you like to pick up meal:",font=('Arial',18, "bold"),bg = '#F0EAD6')
TimeLBL.place(x= 80, y= 575)

TimenBTN15 = Button(frame, text = '15 mins', font=('Arial',16,),bg = '#F0EAD6',command = TimeBTN15 )
TimenBTN15.place(x= 450, y= 575)

TimenBTN30 = Button(frame, text = '30 min ', font=('Arial',16,),bg = '#F0EAD6',command = TimeBTN30 )
TimenBTN30.place(x= 525, y= 575)

TimenBTN1 = Button(frame, text = ' 1 hour', font=('Arial',16,),bg = '#F0EAD6',command = TimeBTN1 )
TimenBTN1.place(x= 600, y= 575)
```